# Cambiar altura dinamicamente ítem RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview

Estoy teniendo un problema al querer cambiar el tamaño dinamicamente la altura de un item, básicamente lo que tengo es lo siguiente
[image: lo que tengo]

la imagen que se muestra, es un RecyclerView y el archivo xml del adapter contiene un CardView que tiene dentro un ImageView y un TexView. El problema es que necesito hacer que la imagen del centro se agrande, por ejemplo en la imagen anterior, tengo al viajero en el centro, este item  debería de agrandarse al ser seleccionado, así:
[image: lo que necesito]

Este seria otro ejemplo cuando el usuario selecciona el item del pájaro
[image: pajaro seleccionado]

El código para llenar el adaptador, las imágenes se llena desde links usando 
[Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

```
dataSet.add(new ImageCard("Viajero Experto","https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/2x/passenger-with-baggage.png"));
        dataSet.add(new ImageCard("Fantasma","https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/2x/sad-ghost.png"));
        dataSet.add(new ImageCard("Viajero","https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/2x/walking.png"));
        recyclerViewImage.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ConfigureProfileActivity.this, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerViewImage.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter =  new MainAdapter(dataSet);
        recyclerViewImage.setAdapter(adapter);
```

El adaptador

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private ArrayList<ImageCard> imageCards;

    public MainAdapter(ArrayList<ImageCard> imageCards)
    {
        this.imageCards = imageCards;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_recycler_view_profile_image,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        holder.title.setText(imageCards.get(position).getNombre());
        Picasso.get().load(imageCards.get(position).getUrl()).resize(260,260).into(holder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return imageCards.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView title;
        public ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar la altura, define una `layoutParams` para tu `ReciclerView` con diferente tamaño de altura, por ejemplo, si deseas cambiarlo a 1000px :

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1000);

recyclerViewImage.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

Comment: gracias, pero lo que necesito en si que cambie de altura es el CardView, no el RecyclerView

Comment: Ok tu pregunta dice : "Cambiar altura dinamicamente ítem RecyclerView".

Comment: perdon por no haberlo escrito bien, pero en la descripcion, estoy diciendo que es lo que me pasa, y dice item RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Si entendi bien estas buscando que se agrande el ViewHolder cuando tenga foco. Esto te dara ese efecto:

```
public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
   super(itemView);
   title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
   image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
   itemView.setOnFocusChangeListener(mOnfocusChangeListener);
}

View.OnFocusChangeListener mOnfocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focused) {
      Animation animation;
      if (focused){
         animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.agrandar);
      }else{
         animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.achicar);
      }
      view.startAnimation(animation);
      animation.setFillAfter(true);
    }
};
```